# Two images separated with vertical line and aligned text with another column

Tags: tikz-pgf, multirow

I am wondering how to achieve the output shown below as "expected result". I would like to have a vertical line between two tikzpictures which has exactly the same height as both images. On the right side there should be a text which is aligned (as a whole block) with the center of the left column (the height of the right column may be different). Is this possible? Thank you in advance.

What I have tried so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}

    \begin{tabular}{c|ll}
        \multirow{2}{*}{\includestandalone[height=40pt]{c1}
        \!} & \multirow{2}{80pt}{\includestandalone[height=40pt]{c2}}
        & \Huge Lorem Ipsum \\ 
          &   & \Huge Lorem Ipsum \\ 
    \end{tabular}

\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

And the tikzpicture:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[blue,thick,dashed] (2,2) circle (3cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Actual result:
[image]
Expected result:
[image]

Comment: Do you HAVE to use standalone (as opposed to \savebox or \includegrahics)?

Comment: @JohnKormylo, will `\includegraphics{img.tex}` give the same result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't say what in the right column should be aligned with the centre of the left column. I'm guessing the centre.

I think that the use of `\includestandalone` here makes things needlessly complicated. However, if you want to use this, you can split out the right column into a `minipage` of whatever width you need.

In the example below, I've framed the boxes, just to show the alignment more clearly. Obviously, you shouldn't include the frames in your actual document.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-1.tex}
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[blue,thick,dashed] (0,0) circle (3cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-2.tex}
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[magenta,thick,dashed] (0,0) circle (3cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,calc}
\usepackage{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  \noindent
  \fbox{\begin{tabular}{c|c}
    \includestandalone[height=40pt]{\jobname-1}
    & \includestandalone[height=40pt]{\jobname-2}
  \end{tabular}}%
  \fbox{\begin{minipage}[c]{.5\linewidth}
    \setlength\parindent{0pt}%
    \Huge Lorem Ipsum\par Lorem Ipsum
  \end{minipage}}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image: aligned columns]

Note that if you simply `\input{}` the Ti*k*Z pictures, you can use `baseline=(current bounding box.center)` and avoid needing to hard-code a width for the `minipage`. However, you cannot then scale the images as easily.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I thought that `\includestandalone` is needed because I want to insert these images as external files. But it seems that `\includegraphics{img.tex}` gives the same result.

Comment: @belford You can say that if you load `tikzscale`, for example. Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes. By the way, did you notice that the line between these two circles is slightly longer? Would it be reasonable to draw this line as a tikzpicture? I mean something like `\begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \includestandalone[height=40pt]{c1}
    & \includestandalone[height=40pt]{c2}
    & \includestandalone[height=40pt]{c3}
  \end{tabular}` Where c2 separates the circles.

Comment: @belford That seems to be overkill, but you could do it that way, of course.